# AnalysisException: u"Except can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am removing the actual column names as i am not supposed to share those
But her is the glimpse of the error

```
AnalysisException: u"Except can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. 
string <> boolean at the 28th column of the second table;
;\n'Except false\n:- Filter (cast(inactive_date#111 as string) = '3001-01-01')\n:  
+- Project [... 33 more fields]\n:+- Project [ ... 33 more fields]\n:+- SubqueryAlias \n:+-Relation[... 33 more fields] parquet\n
+- Project [... 33 more fields]\n +- Join Inner, (Key#275 = entry#26)\n:- Filter (cast(inactive_date#283 as string) = '3001-01-01')\n:  
+- Project [... 33 more fields]\n:  
+- Project [... 33 more fields]\n : +- SubqueryAlias  +- Relation[,... 33 more fields] parquet\n      
+- Deduplicate [entry#26]\n +- Project [entry#26]\n+- Project [... 13 more fields]\n              
+- Project [... 13 more fields]\n  +- SubqueryAlias +- Relation[] parquet\n"
```

My code looks like this

```
#old dataframe   (consider it as History )
#daily dataframe ( Consider it as daily  )

#Filtering the Active records based on condition

Active_old_filtered_records= old_history_dataframe.filter(old_history_dataframe["inactive_date"] == '3001-01-01')
Inactive_old_filtered_records= old_history_dataframe.filter(old_history_dataframe["inactive_date"] != '3001-01-01')

#Joining active old records with the matching active records in daily dataframe based on KeyColumnA 

left = Active_old_filtered_records
right = Active_new_daily_dataframe.select("keyColumnA").distinct()

Matching_Active_daily_old_dataframe = left.join(right, ["keyColumnA"])
Non_matching_active_daily_old_dateframe = Active_old_filtered_records.**subtract**(Matching_Active_daily_old_dataframe)
```

Note: Here the **daily dataframe** and old dataframe have exactly same schema but i am getting analysis exception. can someone help in this regard 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to resolve this with the following code

```
#old dataframe   (consider it as History )
#daily dataframe ( Consider it as daily  )

cols = Active_old_filtered_records.columns

#Filtering the Active records based on condition

Active_old_filtered_records= old_history_dataframe.filter(old_history_dataframe["inactive_date"] == '3001-01-01')
Inactive_old_filtered_records= old_history_dataframe.filter(old_history_dataframe["inactive_date"] != '3001-01-01')

#Joining active old records with the matching active records in daily dataframe based on KeyColumnA 

left = Active_old_filtered_records
right = Active_new_daily_dataframe.select("keyColumnA").distinct()

Matching_Active_daily_old_dataframe = left.join(right, ["keyColumnA"]).select(cols)

Non_matching_active_daily_old_dateframe = Active_old_filtered_records.subtract(Matching_Active_daily_old_dataframe)
```

Joining two dataframes with a column from anywhere except start position changes the order of columns in resultant dataframe. so maintained a cols variable and selected the same column in correct order to ensure the resulting steps work correctly :D

And finally i was able to resolve the problem.